# JAVA - Como arreglar el error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException al tratar de mezclar 2 arrays?

Tags: java, array, netbeans-8.2

Hace poco empece a programar en Java, y un ejercicio de arreglos que me encontre en youtube ha hecho que me quede atorado por un tiempo. El ejercicio es el siguiente:

Ejercicio 14: Leer dos series de 10 enteros,
que estaran ordenados crecientemente.
Copiar( fusionar ) las dos tablas en una tercera,
de forma que sigan ordenados.

Este es mi codigo:

```
                int n1[] = new int[10];//Arreglo 1
                int n2[] = new int[10];//Arreglo 2
                int n3[] = new int[20];//Arreglo 3 donde se fusionan el arreglo 1 y 2
                boolean creciente = false;

                System.out.println("=== INTRODUCIENDO DATOS DEL ARREGLO 1 ===");

                do{
                    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )//Introduciendo datos del arreglo 1
                    {                        
                        System.out.print((i+1)+"- Digite un numero: ");
                        n1[i] = entrada.nextInt();                                                 
                    }

                    //comprobar si el arreglo esta en orden creciente
                    for( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )//Revisando todos los datos del arreglo
                    {
                        if( n1[i] < n1[i+1] )//Si los numeros estan ordenados de manera creciente, la variable se vuelve
                        {                    //verdadera
                            creciente = true;
                        }                              
                        if( n1[i] > n1[i+1] )//En el caso contrario se queda en falso
                        {
                            creciente = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if( creciente == false )//Si el arreglo no esta en forma creciente, se mostrara un mensaje de error
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: El arreglo no esta en forma creciente.\nFavor volver"
                        + " a introducir los datos");
                        System.out.println("\n");
                    }
                }while( creciente == false );//Si el arreglo no esta en forma creciente, se repetira el proceso

                creciente = false;//Iniciammos en falso la variable
                System.out.println("\n=== INTRODUCIENDO DATOS DEL ARREGLO 2 ===");

                do{
                    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )//Introduciendo datos del arreglo 2
                    {                        
                        System.out.print((i+1)+"- Digite un numero: ");
                        n2[i] = entrada.nextInt();                                                  
                    }

                    //comprobar si el arreglo esta en orden creciente
                    for( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )//Si los numeros estan ordenados de manera creciente, la variable se vuelve
                    {                            //verdadera
                        if( n2[i] < n2[i+1] )
                        {
                            creciente = true;
                        }  
                        if( n2[i] > n2[i+1] )//En el caso contrario se queda en falso
                        {
                            creciente = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if( creciente == false )//Si el arreglo no esta en forma creciente, se mostrara un mensaje de error
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: El arreglo no esta en forma creciente.\nFavor volver"
                        + " a introducir los datos");
                        System.out.println("\n");
                    }
                }while( creciente == false );//Si el arreglo no esta en forma creciente, se repetira el proceso

                for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
                {
                    if( n1[i] < n2[i] )//Si el elemento del indice i de n1 es menor al elemento del indice i de n2
                    {                  //se asignara el elemento del indice i de n1
                        n3[i] = n1[i];
                    }                     
                    if( n2[i] < n1[i] )//Si el elemento del indice i de n1 es menor al elemento del indice i de n1
                    {                  //se asignara el elemento del indice i de n2
                        n3[i] = n2[i];
                    }

                    if( n1[i] > n2[9] )//Si los elementos de n1 son mayores al elemento del ultimo indice de n2
                    {                  //se asignaran los elementos restantes de n1
                        n3[i] = n1[i];
                    }
                    else if( n2[i] > n1[9] )//Si los elementos de n2 son mayores al elemento del ultimo indice de n1
                    {                       //se asignaran los elementos restantes de n2
                        n3[i] = n2[i];
                    }                                                
                }

                System.out.println("\n=== EL ARREGLO 3 QUEDA ASI ===");
                for( int k = 0; k < 20; k++ )//Mostramos el resultado
                {
                    System.out.print(n3[k]+" - ");
                }

                System.out.println("\n");
```

No he encontrado porque me da el error de Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tu algoritmo tiene el fallo que te indica @Alfabravo en su respuesta, estás tratando de acceder a un espacio de memoria no asignado.

Existen muchas formas de resolver el problema que te planteas, yo te daré una forma, además añadiré un algoritmo esencial para cualquier programador (algoritmo de la burbuja).

En tu código haces algo que debes evitar a toda costa: "frustrar al usuario". Tienes una condición en la cual, si el usuario no introduce los números de forma creciente, debe volver a empezar a escribir los números uno por uno. Tal vez 10 números no sea para tanto, pero no sabemos las condiciones de uso para el código, por lo tanto es siempre mejor evitar que el usuario se frustre.

Para eso puedes usar el método de la burbuja para asegurarte que los números introducidos, sin importar cómo los introduzca el usuario, serán ordenados de forma ascendente antes de fusionar tus dos arreglos.

Otra cosa que voy a implementar en el código es el principio DRY (*Don't repeat yourself*) o lo que en castellano indica: *No repitas tu código*. En tu programa debes leer 2 veces una serie de 10 números (enteros). Pero eso no significa que debas escribir 2 veces el mismo código. Puedes escribir una función y llamarla 2 veces. De eso trata el principio DRY.

**PROBLEMA**

Cito tu planteamiento: *Leer dos series de 10 enteros, que estaran ordenados crecientemente. Copiar( fusionar ) las dos tablas en una tercera, de forma que sigan ordenados.*

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para resolver el problema primero crearemos un función que nos permita leer los datos introducidos por el usuario. Esta función la llamaremos `llenarArray()` y devolverá un `array` de enteros. A esta función le pasaremos 2 argumentos: una variable tipo string que se llamará `nombre` y que servirá para indicarle al usuario qué `array` está llenando, y otra variable tipo entero que establecerá el tamaño de nuestro array.

Para leer los datos introducidos por el usuario usaremos la librería `Scanner` de `java.util`

El prototipo de la función sería:

```
    public static int[] llenarArray(String nombre, int dimension) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //instanciamos el scanner
    int arr[] = new int[dimension]; // instanciamos el array
    int index = 0; // variable que usaremos de indice para llenar el array
    System.out.println("===" + nombre + "==="); // aqui indicamos el nombre del array que se está llenando (solo informativo)
    System.out.println("Introduzca " + dimension + " números enteros de uno en uno y presione \"ENTER\" (si es negativo incluya delante el signo - ):"); // aceptamos enteros negativos
    while (index < dimension) { // se repite hasta leer todos los enteros
        arr[index] = sc.nextInt(); // llenamos el array
        index++; // incrementamos el indice
    }
    return arr; // devolvemos el array lleno
}
```

Esta sería la función que llamamos cada vez que deseamos llenar un `array`. No hemos puesto comprobación de errores, solo asumimos que el usuario introducirá un entero. Esa comprobación la dejo de tarea.

Ahora que el usuario ha introducido los números enteros (2 veces) haremos uso del método de la burbuja para ordenar los arreglos de forma ascendente. De esta manera nos aseguramos que la fusión se hará con los arreglos ordenados de acuerdo al planteamiento del problema.

Lo curioso aquí es que al fusionar los 2 arreglos, estarás aplicando también el método de la burbuja, pero con 2 arreglos diferentes. Por eso es importante que entiendas el principio fundamental del método de la burbuja para que puedas aplicarlo luego a la fusión.

Como debemos ordenar 2 arreglos, crearemos entonces 1 función la cual llamaremos 2 veces, así seguimos aplicando el principio DRY.

La función la llamaremos `ordenAscendente()` que como su nombre indica ordenará el arreglo de enteros de forma ascendente (de menor a mayor). A esta función le pasaremos como argumento el arreglo que deseamos ordenar. El prototipo de la función sería el siguiente:

```
public static int[] ordenAscendente(int[] arr) { // devuelve un arreglo de enteros
    int pasos = arr.length; // variable que almacena los pasos que debemos dar en cada iteración
    int mayor = 0;  // variable auxiliar que almacenará temporalmente el entero mayor en cada iteración
    while(pasos > 1) {  // ejecutaremos el ciclo hasta que se hayan dado todos los pasos
        for(int i = 0; i < pasos - 1; i++) { // importante: recorreremos el arreglo hasta (pasos - 1) ya que vamos a comparar (i) con (i + 1)
            if(arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) { // si arr[i] es mayor
                mayor = arr[i]; // guardo el mayor
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1]; //asigno el menor
                arr[i + 1] = mayor; //asigno el mayor
            }
        }
        pasos--; // en la primera iteración de while hemos recorrido todo el arreglo
                 // por lo tanto el último elemento es el mayor de todos, reducimos entonces la cantidad de pasos.
    }
    return arr;  // el array devuelto estará ordenado de forma ascendente.
}
```

Seguramente no es fácil entender el algoritmo la primera vez, además esta no es la única forma de implementarlo. Puedes conseguir una explicación un poco mejor en [Ordenamiento de burbuja - Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja).

De Wikipedia he tomado esta imagen que te ayudará a entender el método de ordenamiento de la burbuja de una manera gráfica:

[image: Representación animada de ordenación de un conjunto de números mediante el algoritmo burbuja.]

Ya tenemos las dos funciones auxiliares, ahora debemos escribir el código para fusionar los dos arreglos.

Para continuar con el esquema usado, escribiremos una función que haga la fusión, esta función la haremos de modo que no importe si el tamaño de los arreglos es diferente. Es decir, escribiremos una función más general que específica. Aunque el enunciado del problema habla de 10 números enteros en cada arreglo, nuestra función servirá para cualquier combinación de arreglos, sin importar su tamaño. Así podrías reutilizar el código. Este es parte del mismo principio DRY.

Llamaremos a nuestra función `fusionarDosArrayAscendente()`, como su nombre lo indica, fusionará (copiará) los elementos de 2 arreglos y los ordenará de forma ascendente, en un nuevo arreglo de enteros, cuyo tamaño será la suma de los tamaños de los arreglos.

A esta función le pasaremos como argumentos los 2 arreglos que deseamos fusionar.

El prototipo de la función sería el siguiente:

```
public static int[] fusionarDosArrayAscendente(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    int limArray1 = array1.length; // establecemos el límite para array1 y array2
    int limArray2 = array2.length; // de esta forma evitaremos el error ArrayOutOfBounds
    int dimension = limArray1 + limArray2; // este será el tamaño del nuevo array
    int arr[] = new int[dimension];
    int i = 0; // variables que usaremos como indices de los arreglos
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while ((i + j) < dimension) { // el ciclo se ejecutará hasta que hayamos recorrido los dos arreglos
        if(i < limArray1 && j < limArray2) { // verificamos que podemos acceder a los elementos de ambos arreglos
            if(array1[i] > array2[j]) { // comparamos quien es mayor (ordenamiento de burbuja)
                arr[k] = array2[j]; // guardamos el menor
                j++; // si el menor es array2 incrementamos su indice
            } else {
                arr[k] = array1[i]; // guardamos el menor
                i++;  // si el menor es array1 incrementamos su indice
            }
        } else { // si ya no podemos acceder a alguno de los arreglos (ya lo hemos recorrido completo)
            if(i == limArray1) { // si el que recorrimos completo fue array1 entonces todos los elementos restantes de array2 son mayores
                arr[k] = array2[j]; // guardamos el resto de elementos de array2 (ya están ordenados de forma ascendente)
                j++; //importante: incrementar el indice j
            } else { // si el que recorrimos completo fue array2
                arr[k] = array1[i]; //guardamos el resto de elementos de array1 (ya están ordenados de forma ascendente)
                i++; //importante: incrementar el indice i
            }
        }
        k++;  //importante: incrementar el indice k
    }
    return arr; // devolvemos el nuevo array fusionado.
}
```

Esta función es básicamente el método de la burbuja aplicado sobre 2 arreglos. No hay nada novedoso aquí, excepto la forma en que está estructurado. Como he dicho con anterioridad, hay muchas formas de implementarlo. Esta es la forma en la que yo lo hago.

Ya tenemos todo para implementar el programa. El siguiente código sería una implementación usando las condiciones del problema:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fusionarArray {

    public static int[] ordenAscendente(int[] arr) {
        int pasos = arr.length;
        int mayor = 0;
        while(pasos > 1) {
            for(int i = 0; i < pasos - 1; i++) {
                if(arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                    mayor = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                    arr[i + 1] = mayor;
                }
            }
            pasos--;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static int[] llenarArray(String nombre, int dimension) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arr[] = new int[dimension];
        int index = 0;
        System.out.println("===" + nombre + "===");
        System.out.println("Introduzca " + dimension + " números enteros de uno en uno y presione \"ENTER\" (si es negativo incluya delante el signo -):");
        while (index < dimension) {
            arr[index] = sc.nextInt();
            index++;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static int[] fusionarDosArrayAscendente(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
        int limArray1 = array1.length;
        int limArray2 = array2.length;
        int dimension = limArray1 + limArray2;
        int arr[] = new int[dimension];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        while ((i + j) < dimension) {
            if(i < limArray1 && j < limArray2) {
                if(array1[i] > array2[j]) {
                    arr[k] = array2[j];
                    j++;
                } else {
                    arr[k] = array1[i];
                    i++;
                }
            } else {
                if(i == limArray1) {
                    arr[k] = array2[j];
                    j++;
                } else {
                    arr[k] = array1[i];
                    i++;
                }
            }
            k++;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int dimension1 = 10; //puedes jugar con las dimensiones y el resultado
        int dimension2 = 10; //será el esperado
        // llenamos el primer arreglo
        int primerArray[] = llenarArray("Primer Array", dimension1);
        //llenamos el segundo arreglo
        int segundoArray[] = llenarArray("Segundo Array", dimension2);
        // ordenamos los arreglos
        primerArray = ordenAscendente(primerArray);
        segundoArray = ordenAscendente(segundoArray);
        // fusionamos
        int arrayFusion[] = fusionarDosArrayAscendente(primerArray, segundoArray);
        // mostramos los resultados
        System.out.println("Primer array:");
        for (int i = 0; i < dimension1; i++) {
            System.out.print(primerArray[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Segundo array:");
        for (int i = 0; i < dimension2; i++) {
            System.out.print(segundoArray[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Array fusion:");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayFusion.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arrayFusion[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }
}
```

Espero que esto haya aclarado tu duda.

Comment: No solamente me respondiste, sino que me ayudaste a optimizar mi codigo y me ahorraste la busqueda en google. Muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver el ejercicio te sugiero utilizar for aninados, asi como lo tienes te genera error debido a que recorres el n3 en un for y a la misma vez recorres los arreglos n1 y n2 que no cuentan con las posiciones del 10 en adelante.

Tambien como mejora te siguiero utilizar `array.length` y no los "numeros magicos" que tienes en las condiciones de los for.

Ejemplo for aninado:

`for(int x = 0; x < n1.length; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < n2.length; y++) {`

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaba con dolor de cabeza de buscar el error. Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Estás recorriendo los tres arreglos con un mismo contador.

```
 for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
                {
                    if( n1[i] < n2[i] )//Si el elemento del indice i de n1 es menor al elemento del indice i de n2
                    {                  //se asignara el elemento del indice i de n1
                        n3[i] = n1[i];
```

En el penúltimo for. Si vas a ir hasta 20, claro que te vas a salir de los arreglos 1 y 2.