# Java: Leer dos arreglos diferentes que contienen números enteros y crear un tercer arreglo

Tags: java, array

Se me propuso realizar este ejercicio en java... "Leer dos arreglos diferentes que contienen números enteros y crear un tercer arreglo. Donde en forma secuencial ingresen en el tercer arreglo los elementos. Ejemplificando o representando los dos arreglos".

[image: Imagen del ejemplo propuesto]

He hecho el siguiente código que da solución al ejercicio.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);
int [] impares = new int [10]; 
int [] pares = new int [10]; 
int [] fusion = new int [impares.length + pares.length]; 
     
    
        for (int a = 0; a < impares.length; a++) {

            System.out.println("Ingrese un numero en la posición ["+a+"] del Arreglo Impares.");
            impares[a]=entrada.nextInt();                
        }
        for (int b = 0; b < pares.length; b++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese un numero en la posición ["+b+"] del Arreglo Pares.");
            pares[b]=entrada.nextInt();
        }
        
    int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
        fusion[j]= impares[i];
        j++;
        fusion[j]= pares[i];
        j++;
    }
    
    System.out.println("\n \n Al juntar los dos arreglos el resultado es: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < fusion.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(fusion[i]+"");
    }
    
}
```

La ayuda que necesito, es a corregir el siguiente ciclo for, cuando el valor de los arreglos es desiguales. Por ejemplo suponiendo que al arreglo "impares" lo inicializo con longitud de 8 y el arreglo "pares" lo inicializo con longitud 9.

```
int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
        fusion[j]= impares[i];
        j++;
        fusion[j]= pares[i];
        j++;
    }
```

Ya le he intentado poniendo la longitud de uno de los dos arreglos, mas sin embargo siempre me sale error, como también intenté sumar las dos longitudes de los dos arreglos en ese for, pero igual no logro que la ejecución termine de forma correcta.

Agradezco desde ya a quienes me ayuden con sus respuestas, estoy aprendiendo desarrollo de software y java es una de las materias que estamos viendo.

Comment: Relacionado: [JAVA - Como arreglar el error Exception in thread “main” java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException al tratar de mezclar 2 arrays?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/233766/java-como-arreglar-el-error-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-arrayindexout/234027#234027). El problema es que estás *hardcodeando* el tamaño o dimensión del array, debes calcularlo dinamicamente. En la respuesta que enlazo se explica como. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debido a que los 2 tendrán valores diferentes una manera de solucionarlo seria la siguiente.

Para no tener que ingresar el valor que tendra tu arreglo final `fusion` puedes utilizar sin problemas `fusion.length`

```
for (int i = 0; i < fusion.length; i++) {
    if (i < impares.length) {
        fusion[j] = impares[i];
        j++;
    }
    if (i < pares.length) {
        fusion[j] = pares[i];
        j++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Saludos @Richard, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, tenia la percepción de usar un IF pero me rompia la cabeza pensando como lo hacia, tu respuesta me sirvió, y soluciono el error que tenia.