# Fusionar arrays y no arrojar números repetidos

Tags: java

Diseñar un programa que indique la fusión entre dos vectores de cadenas de caracteres. La fusión no debe tener elementos repetidos, es decir, si un elemento se encuentra en ambos vectores, en la fusión solo debe aparecer una vez.

Solo llevo la lectura de los dos primeros vectores pero no sé como hacer que el tercer vector tome los valores ingresados del primer y segundo vector, tampoco la condición para que no me muestre los números repetidos, es decir, si un número se repite, solo lo muestre una vez. Aclaro que lo estoy haciendo en un jFrame.

Código

```
int tam = Integer.parseInt(cajatextovecuno.getText());
    int tam2 = Integer.parseInt(cajatextovecdos.getText());
    String []Vec1= new String [tam];
    String []Vec2= new String [tam2]; 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "VECTOR UNO");
    for (int i = 0; i < Vec1.length; i++) {
        Vec1[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el elemento de la 
    posicion "+ i);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "VECTOR DOS");
    for (int i = 0; i < Vec2.length; i++) {
        Vec2[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el elemento de la 
    posicion "+ i);
    }
```

Comment: Hola @Santiago Mantila Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Por favor intenta que tu  [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) esté en formato código en vez de imagen. Te invito a que revises las recomendaciones en [¿como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por favor, copia y pega el código. La gente que responde aquí muchas veces necesita copiar y pegar tu código en su IDE para probar ciertas cosas y si pones una imagen se hace tan tedioso hacerlo a mano que la mayoría decide dejar la pregunta de lado.

Comment: Relacionado: [JAVA - Como arreglar el error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException al tratar de mezclar 2 arrays?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/233766/java-como-arreglar-el-error-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-arrayindexout/234027#234027)

Comment: Puedes usar Sets?

Comment: Te refieres a setText? O parecido? Todo es algo básico pero si es nuevo no estaría mal aprenderlo, no hay problema

Comment: *java.util.Set*; normalmente usarás como implementación *java.util.HashSet*

Comment: @SantiagoMantilla como se nota que es un problema de clase, no sé si tu profesor te permitirá usar Sets, ya que es un concepto un poco más avanzado a los arrays pero que te solucionaría la vida en dos líneas.

Answer (score 0):

la idea es primero unir los arreglos y luego crear un metodo aparte que haga un nuevo arreglo sin que se repitan:

```
package ejerciciosmedios;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 * @author jhfranco2
 */
public class union {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] A = {8,4,1,2};
        int [] B = {2,3,9,1,2};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sinRepetir(union(A,B))));
        // c = {1,2,3,4,8,9} 
    }
    public static int[] union(int [] a,int[]b){
    int [] c = new int[a.length+b.length];
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    c[i] = a[i];
    }
    int x = 0;
    for(int i = a.length;i<a.length+b.length;i++){
    c[i] = b[x++];
    }
    return c;
    }
   public static int[] sinRepetir(int[]a){
   Arrays.sort(a);
   int len = a.length;
   int j = 0;
   for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++){
       if(a[i]!=a[i+1]){
          a[j++] = a[i];
       }
   }
   a[j++] = a[len-1];
   int [] c = new int[j];
   for(int k = 0;k<j;k++){
   c[k] = a[k];
   }
   return c;
   }
   
}
```

Comment: ya esta editada y le di un ejemplo, ahora me pueden quitar el voto negativo por favor, solo quería darle un poco de promoción a mi canal

Comment: ok, ya borro entonces el enlace

Comment: ya le di positivo yo

Answer (score 0):

Una vez que tenes tus dos arreglos: Vec1 y Vec2 (como recomendación te recuerdo que por convención los nombres de las variables van en minúscula) podes utilizar apache commons para unir los dos arreglos:

[apacheCommons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29)

```
String[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(Vec1, Vec2);
```

Despues podes convertir el arreglo resultante en un Set. Recordemos que la colección Set no permite duplicados, asique resuelve el problema por vos :D

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(both));
```

Desde este punto podes trabajar con el Set o en caso de necesitar un Array podes usar la siguiente linea:

```
String[] finalArray = new String[set.size()];
set.toArray(finalArray);
```

Esto te deja un Array de String sin repetidos :D

Answer (score 0):

Desde [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) ya puedes usar el API de fjulos o Stream API por su nombre en inglés.

La clase `Arrays` ahora incluye un método para convertir un arreglo de cualquier tipo a un stream (`Arrays.stream`).

Los streams adicionalmente se puede concatenar (`Stream.concat`), así que lo único restante es filtrar para que solo contenga elementos distintos, y juntar el resultado, estos dos pasos se pueden hacer en un solo paso mediante un colector, para simplificar el proceso, ya vienen algunos colectores comunes en la clase `Collectors`, como en este caso `Collectors.joining` que es un método fábrica estático.

Por ejemplo:

```
    String[] Vec1 = {"Hello", "Sick", "Sad", "World!"};
    String[] Vec2 = {"Hello", "Beautiful", "World!"};
    String union = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(Vec1), Arrays.stream(Vec2))
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    System.out.println(union);
```

Como te imaginarás las salida de ese programa es:

> Hello Sick Sad World! Beautiful

Como verás puedes usas un colector de unión sin parámetros o como en este ejemplo, especificar una cadena para concatenarla en el colector.